# Ceiling fan speed controller question

Tags: fan

I need to connect 15 ceiling fans. Each bay has 3 ceiling fans that will run of the same speed controller, so 5 controllers in total. They will be wired from a separate circuit from the DB box. Here's the schematic below that I drew up:
[image: Schematic]

Since each fan pulls about 0.5 amps, that's about 7.5 amps total, so a 15-20 amps circuit breaker should be fine. For the fan controller though, i'm guessing I'll have to buy one that can control 3 fans, since the capacitors in the fan controller are gonna see roughly 1.5 amps, hence the voltage drop across them will change compared to when connected to a single fan ?

Comment: What "capacitors in the fan controller" do you refer to?

Comment: @Andyaka, I read about ceiling fan controllers and they say they just have different value capacitors on each speed selector. The higher the capacitance, the smaller the impedance (1/2*pi*f*c) and the faster the fan spins

Comment: If you only need speed you might consider the usual remote kits set the codes the same and maybe customize a transmitter.  But if you have lights you would have to deal with those another way as that is essentially always a toggle function with state held in the receiver.

Comment: Just be aware that even though the fans have a total rated load of 7.5A, their startup current will be much much higher.  You want the lowest practicable breaker and overload ratings, so you may find a need to stagger the fan startup if your 15A breaker pops frequently.